# jQuery UI Tabs: Non-standard markup structure

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

The jQuery UI Tabs plugin by default expects a markup structure like this:

```
<div id="tabs"> 
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li> 
</ul> 
<div id="tabs-1"> 
    <p>Content 1</p> 
</div> 
<div id="tabs-2"> 
    <p>Content 2</p> 
</div> 
<div id="tabs-3"> 
    <p>Content 3</p>
</div> 
</div>
```

meaning that there is a top-level container ("tabs" in this case) with a ul inside it and several divs, allowing tab activation with a simple

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

However, this is unacceptable for me since I need a more complex structure. Namely, the ul is contained (along with other elements) inside another container div, and the panels are inside yet another one:

```
<div id="tabs"> 
<div id="container-1">
    <div id="inside"></div>
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
<div id="panels">
    <div id="tabs-1"> 
        <p>Content 1</p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="tabs-2"> 
        <p>Content 2</p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="tabs-3"> 
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div> 
</div>
<div id="outside"></div>
</div>
```

I now want the ul inside container-1 to provide the tabs for the divs inside panels. How is that possible?

Comment: `$('#container-1').appendTo('#panels')`??? but why must you have that structure? and make that extra more difficult for yourself?

Comment: I need extra styling (frame around ul and other elements, but not around panels). Therefore, your suggestion won't work.

Comment: why don't you use layers instead of changing the structure? make a jsfiddle.net file of what you want we can re-organise it so it looks the same but coded diferently

Comment: Seems a lot of work for such a simple task. Really, all I need is a way to specify to jQuery UI which selector should be used to make the tabs and which one to make the panels, rather than it using its defaults. jQuery Tools [link](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) has a tab control that works just like that. Unfortunately, I cannot use jQuery Tools since it conflicts with jQuery UI.

Comment: Thats the problem sortable has an option for items... but not tabs, [unfortunatly] ... Another thing you could do, is override the panels, but like I said show us what you need to be done to it?

Comment: I already have shown it. I need precisely the HTML structure from the code above, no deviation possible. From your answer, and my own research, it appears that this is indeed impossible, which makes jQuery UI Tabs a much less flexible tool than I had expected. The problem is simply Tabs' hard-coded structure, making it unsuitable for my needs.

Comment: Jens is a new user and she needs at least 10 points [i think] :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort in helping me, Val! I'll probably end up building a custom version of jQuery UI that doesn't conflict with Tools and use that.